# How to return index.html page with JEE7 without web.xml

Tags: servlets, java-ee-7

How to return index.html page with JEE7 without web.xml?
I cannot find nothing on the internet and the official oracle docs says to use web.xml.

Please help

Comment: What is your servlet mapping?

Comment: You mean Web.xml? Here is project https://github.com/masterdany88/erp2/blob/master/access/accessAdapter/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml